Netty blocking spring integration workers
Currently I’m working on a spring integration service that uses webClient with Netty for http calls
The problem that I'm facing occurs when spring integration goes to a channel and while it is executing the "activator code", it uses webClient to make http calls
This problem is intermittent, and it happens when during the execution of the activator, it will execute webclient(reactive) and the assignment of reactive threads is taking several minutes (up to 20 some times) in which any new activator that requires to do an http call is stuck waiting for an assignment of a reactive thread, and then suddenly all of them are assigned and initiate the calls normally. Seems like something was block preventing new requests from happening and then was released
also it is important to mention that it is an ocp cluster with pod CPU request is 50m, however the traffic is not that high as I’ll expect for this to happen
I also want to mention that when I execute the web client reactor mechanism I’m calling subscribe() and then block() for the mono
    var shared = mono.share();

    shared.subscribe();

    shared.block();

Any idea of what can be happening ?
I have tried in my local with more cores, and by hammering with hundreds of requests I'm able to see hanging threads up to 2 minutes and never as much to what we see in OCP cluster
I’ll expect that in local with more cores it goes well, but it is not
Here is an example of the logs:
{"timestamp":"2024-07-10T04:30:42.575-04:00","level":"DEBUG","thread":"pool-50-thread-61","mdc":{"logCount":"4836","UID":"XXX4836D"},"logger":"org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions","message":"[4b9cdd0a] HTTP POST https://host/endpoint","context":"default"}

{"timestamp":"2024-07-10T04:39:08.304-04:00","level":"DEBUG","thread":"reactor-http-epoll-2","mdc":{"logCount":"2238","UID":"XXX2238D"},"logger":"reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient","message":"[0c6303a5] REGISTERED","context":"default"}
    

This is the same "execution", but notice the times :
2024-07-10T04:30:42.575-04:00
2024-07-10T04:39:08.304-04:00
9 minutes to get a thread in netty

Would be great to have some simple project to reproduce on our side. Perhaps indeed that Mono.block() is not OK.

@ArtemBilan I just added the block where I'm using "Mono.block"

If you use block(), you don't need subscribe(). Otherwise you subscribe to the same Mono twice.

Hey @ArtemBilan, I added an example of logs, notice that this is not always happening

Doesn't say anything to me. The sample project to play on our side would be great. I'm not good with Netty though.

Note,
It is not subscribed twice, it is subscribed to wait for that response without blocking the main thread
Why do you say it is twice?
It will take time to create a project with that error

Because subscribe() and block() does exactly the same. So, you create two subscribers to the same Mono.

What we are trying is to "subscribe" to a different scheduler so when we do block, we do not block the main thread

Why is that? The block() is definitely blocking the thread which calls this block(). For different thread for subscription you can look into Mono.subscribeOn().

without any code this unanswerable. And the rule is simple, you do not block/subscribe in a reactive application. Period. Why? because all events are handled by the event loop, and blocking will make the event loop stop. You are talking about main thread etc. There is no "main thread" in reactive, more than a thread that is named "main" it has no more importance than any other thread. reactive uses NIO threads, and they are not to be blocked. If you call block, the scheduler will shedule this blocking job on the event loop, the event loop will then block.

I understand, that's not the case, since we are using the shared() method we are getting the first result in that way we are not subscribed twice
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#shareNext--
But still, it is not happening constantly
Another thing that we noticed today is that after increasing the resources, we are not having errors so far.
But we think it should be a better answer than just increase the resources
because, why it will take those randoms several minutes to continue ?
